# Como acessar o "this" de uma classe com uma função externa?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Quero criar uma função, dentro de uma classe, que é definida externamente, mas não consigo acessar o `this` da classe.
Exemplo:

```js
class minhaClasse {
  constructor(objeto){
    this.meuNumero = objeto.meuNumero
    this.minhaFuncao = objeto.minhaFuncao;
  }
}

var meuObjeto = new minhaClasse({
  meuNumero: 4,
  minhaFuncao: ()=>{
    console.log(this.meuNumero)
    //log esperado: 4

    this.meuNumero++;
    console.log(this.meuNumero)
    //log esperado: 5
  }
})

meuObjeto.minhaFuncao();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Troque o arrow-function:

```
minhaFuncao: () => {
```

por function normal:

```
minhaFuncao: function () {
```

Assim:

```js
class minhaClasse {
  constructor(objeto){
    this.meuNumero = objeto.meuNumero
    this.minhaFuncao = objeto.minhaFuncao;
  }
}

var meuObjeto = new minhaClasse({
  meuNumero: 4,
  minhaFuncao: function () {
    console.log(this.meuNumero)
    //log esperado: 4

    this.meuNumero++;
    console.log(this.meuNumero)
    //log esperado: 5
  }
})

meuObjeto.minhaFuncao();
```

Apesar de ter virado moda usar arrow-function e de ter gente achando que esse é o novo modo de se fazer as coisas é um engano, na verdade arrow-function tem um motivo especifico para existir, fora facilitar um pouco o uso do return, o arrow proporciona acessar o contexto do local que é "declarado" como se pertencesse ao mesmo contexto, ou seja, se tiver um `this` fora da função ele será acessível (o que não é o caso do que você usou, é diferente)

Por exemplo:

```js
function Foo()
{
     this.foo = 1000;
     
     function bar() {
          return this.foo; //Não vai funcionar, será undefined
     }
     
     this.response = bar();
}

let teste = new Foo;
console.log(teste.response);
```

Enquanto com arrow vai ficar acessivel:

```js
function Foo()
{
     this.foo = 1000;
     
     var bar = () => {
          return this.foo; //Vai funcionar, será 1000
     };
     
     this.response = bar();
}

let teste = new Foo;
console.log(teste.response);
```

Isso também poderia ser um `return` implícito":

```
var bar = () => this.foo;
```

Ou seja, `function ()` não é obsoleto, nem deixou de ser usado, é simplesmente que ambos tem hora e lugar para usar, como foi no caso do seu código, o correto a usar é `function ()`

Comment: Meu deus, não acredito que era algo tão simples.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: @LuísHNrique por nada, atualizei a resposta com detalhes sobre ambos, arrow e function... se puder marque a resposta como correta. Grato